# angular-material2, set pageIndex of paginator to 0 when submit a form does not update view

Tags: angular, angular-material2

steps:

1. input a keyword and submit the form. when getting the data, the `paginator` display the first page `1-10 of 400`.
2. go to page 2, `paginator` display `11-20 of 400`
3. **submit the form again with the same keyword which means the input is not changed.**
4. **I want the `paginator` back to its initial state which means it should be displayed`1-10 of NaN`.** So I set the `paginator.pageIndex = 0`.
5. I console the `paginator` component instance, and find the `pageIndex` property has been set to `0`. **But the view of `paginator` still display `11-20 of 400`.**

ts:

```js
public onSubmit(): void {
  const firstPage: number = this.pageIndex + 1;
  this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
  console.log(this.paginator)
  this.diseaseDataBase.getDiseasesByPage(this.keyword, firstPage);
}
```

html:

```html
<md-paginator
  (page)="onPageChange($event)"
  [length]="diseaseDataBase.total"
  [pageIndex]="0"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
>
</md-paginator>
```

Comment: FYI for other readers, this is a bug right now and fix will be part of beta.9 release, [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6220)

Comment: @Nehal Thanks. I commit the github issue. by the way, how can I find the date of every release?

Comment: Old releases? You can find them [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). New release dates are uncertain, usually depends on the material teams prep.

Comment: @Nehal ok. thanks.